# (SQL Server) return sub-string value after 1st occurrence of 'character'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a column in which contains data like 10374-0-dd.txt or 1037424444-0-dd.txt

I was currently doing -
    SUBSTRING(sa.FileName, 9,100) to return the file name from the 9th position that is (dd.text) but now there is an issue the starting no. of numerals vary.

How do i return the filename regardless of the number of characters in front of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUBSTRING_INDEX, they can get the last substring start with "-"

**Sample**

```
MariaDB []> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('10374-0-dd.txt', '-', -1);
+--------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('10374-0-dd.txt', '-', -1) |
+--------------------------------------------+
| dd.txt                                     |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('10374-0--1234-56789-hallo.txt', '-', -1) ;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('10374-0--1234-56789-hallo.txt', '-', -1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| hallo.txt                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Comment: what if the data is like this

 76189-0-SAmple word doc - TLP ffffff.docx
76152-0-noname-11.eml
77196-0-Template_administrator_administrator_22-01-2016-01-02-19.xlsx
76187-0-administrator_Ticket_53028120715070737_.docx

??

Comment: Where should he cut? give me the rule for this

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, the goal is to return the filename starting from the first character,

Also, i get this error when i run this - "'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.
"

Comment: So, Sorry i forgot to mention in SQL Server